# LogicalExpand does not work correct?

Tags: equation-solving, algebraic-manipulation

I have a boolean expression and need to distribute all it's part. I  used LogicalExpand and it works fine somehow. but I see for some sub-parts it does not Simpify or solve it. I tried Simplify for whole relations but it does not help. please look this sample:

```
LogicalExpand[ x == xP &&  z == zP && ((w ==  wP && ((x + z == yP && z >= 0) || (x + 2 z == yP && w  
< x &&  z < 0 && w <= x + 2 z))) || (wP == 4 + x && x + 2 z == yP && (w >= x || x + 2 z < w) && (w < x || z < 0)))]

 ( wP == w && xP == x && x + z == yP && zP == z &&  z >= 0)
 || ( 4 + x == wP && xP == x && x + 2 z == yP && zP == z && w >= x && w < x) # issue
 || ( 4 + x == wP && xP == x && x + 2 z == yP && zP == z && w >= x && z < 0)
 || ( 4 + x == wP && xP == x && x + 2 z == yP && zP == z && w < x &&  x + 2 z < w)
 || (4 + x == wP && xP == x &&  x + 2 z == yP && zP == z && z < 0 && x + 2 z < w)
 || ( wP == w && xP == x && x + 2 z == yP && zP == z && w < x && z < 0 && w <= x + 2 z)
```

as you see in second line **w >= x && w < x** means Flase. But logicalExpand only expanded the relations without making final reduce or something. How can I remove the second which become false without furthur reduce for each sub-part? note that this relations happens automaticaly in my program and I must create proper command before sending it to Mathematica Kernel. The output format is completely OK and I must have it like this. ***using Simplify will change the style of output,it will change it to UnExpanded again, mixing the relations which is not my desire.
thanks***

Comment: `Simplify` the result.

Comment: @BillWatts yes I mentioned in th question . Actually it helps and it does not help. Simplify will again make it UnExpanded. which is not my desire. it will remove that issue but the format will change.

Comment: @BillWatts yes. but this is just one example. this program makes different reltions each time. so  I want something that works all the time without manual works. i thought there might be some funtion that resolve it automatically.

Comment: Try `Reduce` on the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `LogicalExpand` will typically produce an expression of the form `Or[cond1,cond2,…]` (`cond1||cond2||…`), you can [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) (`/@`) [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) over this result. This simplifies down the individual branches (`cond1`,`cond2`,…), but will leave the top-level untouched:

```
Simplify /@ 
 LogicalExpand[
  x == xP && 
   z == zP && ((w == 
        wP && ((x + z == yP && z >= 0) || (x + 2 z == yP && w < x && 
           z < 0 && w <= x + 2 z))) || (wP == 4 + x && 
       x + 2 z == yP && (w >= x || x + 2 z < w) && (w < x || z < 0)))]
(* (w == wP && x == xP && x + z == yP && z == zP && 
   z >= 0) || (wP == 4 + x && x == xP && x + 2 z == yP && z == zP && 
   w >= x && z < 0) || (wP == 4 + x && x == xP && x + 2 z == yP && 
   z == zP && w < x && x + 2 z < w) || (wP == 4 + x && x == xP && 
   x + 2 z == yP && z == zP && z < 0 && x + 2 z < w) || (w == wP && 
   x == xP && x + 2 z == yP && z == zP && w < x && z < 0 && 
   w <= x + 2 z) *)
```